# How to test Gulp tasks

Tags: unit-testing, gulp

Since I started using Gulp, my project got bigger. Now I have a few quite fancy tasks and now I'm wondering maybe I should build some unit tests to keep some sanity?

Is there a good and simple way to load Gulpfile and make sure my tasks are doing what I want them to do?

Anybody ever tested their scripts, or it's absolute waste of time?

Comment: I've never thought of a build script being an appropriate thing to unit-test because there aren't really inputs and outputs that you can assert on. I'd be keen to see how you get on with it though!

Comment: me neither, but as I said - the script is getting heavier and some tasks becoming cumbersome. I guess the right thing would be to extend some tasks into separated gulp plugins, and those can and should be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to reduce complexity may be modularizing tasks and putting them in separate files. In this case you may need to share gulp instance and gulp plugins. I did it this way:

in `Gulpfile.coffee`:

```
gulp = require 'gulp'
$ = require('gulp-load-plugins')()

require('./src/build/build-task')(gulp, $)

gulp.task "default", ['build']
```

in `./src/build/build-task.coffee`:

```
module.exports = (gulp, $)->    
   gulp.task "build",->
       $.util.log "running build task"
```

Although some may argue that this approach would make it even more complex and it's maybe better to keep everything in Gulpfile, however it worked for me, and it almost feels I can live with no tests now.

Comment: This is a good practice, but doesn't address testing the gulp tasks.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't answer the question of how to actually test gulp. Hendra Uzia's answer looks to be a complete answer.

Answer (score 13):

My approach is to create a test instance and use `exec` and [yeoman-assert](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman-assert/blob/master/index.js). Though it feels more like an integration test, I find it helpful to be sure the tasks run properly ([my use case being a yeoman-generator](https://github.com/johannesjo/generator-modular-angular)). Some (mocha) example:

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var helpers = require('yeoman-generator').test;
var assert = require('yeoman-generator').assert;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');
var injectStyles = require('../.test-instance/tasks/dev');


describe('gulp inject', function ()
{
    var instancePath = path.join(__dirname, '../.test-instance');
    var mainScss = path.join(instancePath, 'app/styles/main.scss');
    var gulpfile = path.join(instancePath, 'gulpfile.js');
    var gulp = '$(which gulp)';
    var injectStylesCmd = gulp + ' injectStyles';

    describe('scss partials in styles folder', function ()
    {
        var expectedContent = [
            [mainScss, /_variables/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_buttons\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_fonts\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_forms\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_icons\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_lists\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_page\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_tables\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /base\/_typography\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /functions\/_some-function\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /mixins\/_some-mixin\.scss/],
            [mainScss, /placeholders\/_some-placeholder\.scss/]
        ];
        var expected = [
            mainScss
        ];


        beforeEach(function (done)
        {
            this.timeout(10000);
            fs.truncateSync(mainScss);
            fs.writeFileSync(mainScss, '// inject:sass\n\n// endinject');
            exec(injectStylesCmd + ' injectStyles', {
                cwd: instancePath
            }, function (err, stdout)
            {
                done();
            });
        });

        it('creates expected files', function ()
        {
            assert.file([].concat(
                expected
            ));
            assert.fileContent([].concat(
                expectedContent
            ));
        });
    });
});
```

Of course you need to make sure, that you have a test-instance set up. You can create your testing files via `fs.writeFileSync` for example. In most cases you need to make sure that the instance has the same directory structure and that at the very least the gulpfile is present.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige thanks for the pointer, looks absolutely promising! I was wondering... how do you handle the `npm install` process before running the build test?

Comment: I'm using a makefile for that: https://github.com/johannesjo/generator-modular-angular/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: That make sense... I've added an `exec` statement in the before each https://github.com/open-cloud/xos/blob/master/views/ngXosLib/generator-xos/test/build.spec.js#L47-L65 (it still need to be refactored using promises... but it works)

Answer (score 7):

I found that looking at unit tests from gulp plugins (ex: https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref/tree/master/test) is a good starting point to writing your own.

The solution that worked for me in the end (main interest was the build process) is not to test the gulp tasks individually but have directories with source files, copy the source files in place, run gulp ('gulp build' as shell command) and compare the output directories and files with with another directory with holding the correct output. –

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR

I do create tests for my task, there are 2 kind of tests that I created for gulp tasks:

- Unit tests, e.g. for conditions, options, etc.
- Integration tests, e.g. stream input, stream output, etc.

To make sure it can be tested easily, I modularize everything from the task to the gulp plugin.

***Unit Test***

1. Create adapters for each gulp plugin.
2. Use the adapter in the modularized task.
3. Spy on the adapter and add debug property on the stream.
4. Assert any condition and stream sequences.

***Integration Test***

1. Build input
2. Run gulp task
3. Output to temp location

---

## Really Long Answer

Enough the chit-chat, here's a unit test mixed with integration test example using jasmine:

```
/* spec/lib/tasks/build_spec.js */
var gulp     = require("gulp");
var through2 = require("through2");
var exec     = require("child_process").exec;
var env      = require("../../../lib/env");
var build    = require("../../../lib/tasks/build");
var gulpif   = require("../../../lib/adapters/gulpif");
var gzip     = require("../../../lib/adapters/gzip");
var uglify   = require("../../../lib/adapters/uglify");

describe("build", function(){
  it("stream to uglify then gzip if environment is production", function(testDone){
    var streamSequence = [];

    // 1. Stub condition and output path
    spyOn(env, "production").and.returnValue(true);
    spyOn(build, "dest").and.returnValue("./tmp");

    // 2. Stub debug message for stream sequence 
    spyOn(gulpif, "stream").and.callFake(function(env, stream){
      if (env.production()) streamSequence.push(stream.debug["stream-name"]);
      return through2.obj();
    });
    spyOn(uglify, "stream").and.callFake(function(){
      var stream = through2.obj();
      stream.debug = { "stream-name": "stream-uglify" };
      return stream;
    });
    spyOn(gzip, "stream").and.callFake(function(){
      var stream = through2.obj();
      stream.debug = { "stream-name": "stream-gzip" };
      return stream;
    });

    var stream = build.run();
    var url = "file://" + process.cwd() + "/tmp/resource.js";
    stream.on("end", function(){

      // 3. Assert stream sequence (unit test)
      expect(streamSequence).toEqual(["stream-uglify", "stream-gzip"]);
      exec("curl " + url, function(error, stdout, stderr){

        // 4. Assert stream output (integration)
        expect(eval.bind(Object.create(null), stdout)).not.toThrow();
        testDone();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Here's the module example for the task:

```
/* lib/tasks/build.js */
var gulp   = require("gulp");
var env    = require("../env");
var gulpif = require("../adapters/gulpif");
var gzip   = require("../adapters/gzip");
var uglify = require("../adapters/uglify");

var build = {
  dest: function(){
    return "./path/to/output";
  },
  run: function(){
    return gulp.src("./path/to/resource.js")
      .pipe(gulpif.stream(env.production(), uglify.stream()))
      .pipe(gulpif.stream(env.production(), gzip.stream()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(this.dest()));
  }
};

module.exports = build;
```

Here are the adapters:

```
/* lib/adapters/gulpif.js */
var gulpif = require("gulp-if");
var adapter = {
  stream: function(){
    return gulpif.apply(Object.create(null), arguments);
  }
};
module.exports = adapter;

/* lib/adapters/gzip.js */
var gzip = require("gulp-gzip");
var adapter = {
  stream: function(){
    return gzip.apply(Object.create(null), arguments);
  }
};
module.exports = adapter;

/* lib/adapters/uglify.js */
var gzip = require("gulp-uglify");
var adapter = {
  stream: function(){
    return uglify.apply(Object.create(null), arguments);
  }
};
module.exports = adapter;
```

Here's the environment to demonstrate condition testing:

```
/* lib/env.js */
var args = require("yargs").argv;
var env = {
  production: function(){
    return (args.environment === "production");
  }
}
```

And last, here's the task that uses the task module example:

```
/* tasks/build.js */
var gulp = require("gulp");
var build = require("./lib/tasks/build");
gulp.task("build", function(){
  build.run();
});
```

I know it's not perfect, and there are some duplicated code. But I hope this can give you a demonstration of how I tested my task.